# nvarchar vs varchar \ IN vs JOIN

Tags: t-sql, comparison, missing-data, nvarchar

Question regarding "IN" versus "INNER JOIN" and VARCHAR versus NVARCHAR

Examples lay it out...

This query returns the CORRECT results (11 count):

Uses nvarchar(10) data columns for comparison (Id and Location) via INNER JOIN

```
    SELECT b.Location
    FROM  [configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer] a
    inner join [configuration].[dbo].[M3_WarehouseInventory] b
        on a.Id = b.Location
    WHERE  1=1 
        and b.[WarehouseId] = 'NCL'
        AND a.[Status] <> '90'
    GROUP BY b.[Location], a.Id
```

This query returns the CORRECT records (11 count):

Uses the same query above as a sub-query, still comparing the same columns but using IN, and adds a forced CONVERT from NVARCHAR to VARCHAR.

```
SELECT *
FROM  [configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer]
WHERE  1=1 
   AND convert(varchar(10),[configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer].[Id]) in (
        SELECT convert(varchar(10),b.Location)
        FROM  [configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer] a
        inner join [configuration].[dbo].[M3_WarehouseInventory] b
            on a.Id = b.Location
        WHERE  1=1 
            and b.[WarehouseId] = 'NCL'
            AND  a.[Status] <> '90'
        GROUP BY b.[Location], a.Id
   )
```

This query returns INCORRECT results (10 count):

Only difference between this query and above is the comparison columns are converted to NVARCHAR

```
SELECT *
FROM  [configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer]
WHERE  1=1 
   AND convert(nvarchar(10),[configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer].[Id]) in (
        SELECT convert(nvarchar(10),b.Location)
        FROM  [configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer] a
        inner join [configuration].[dbo].[M3_WarehouseInventory] b
            on a.Id = b.Location
        WHERE  1=1 
            and b.[WarehouseId] = 'NCL'
            AND  a.[Status] <> '90'
        GROUP BY b.[Location], a.Id
   )
```

This is the original query that returned INCORRECT results - 10 records, should be returning 11 records:

The issue is associated to the difference between an INNER JOIN and IN - as well as - varchar vs nvarchar

```
SELECT  *
FROM  [configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer] 
WHERE  1=1 
    AND [configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer].[Id] IN (
        SELECT [configuration].[dbo].[M3_WarehouseInventory].[Location]
        FROM  [configuration].[dbo].[M3_WarehouseInventory] 
        WHERE  1=1
            and [configuration].[dbo].[M3_WarehouseInventory].[WarehouseId] = 'NCL'
        GROUP BY [configuration].[dbo].[M3_WarehouseInventory].[Location]
    ) 
        AND  [configuration].[dbo].[M3_Customer].[Status] <> '90'
```

---

The INNER JOIN logic works with nvarchar.
The IN logic works when converting to varchar.
The IN logic using nvarchar failed to return a single record.

We applied LTRIM(RTRIM() to all columns at one point but that did not resolve the issue.

Only using the combination of IN and converting the comparison columns to varchar - resolved the issue.

Why?

Comment: Also [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable. Get in the habit of using *good* aliases too. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](//sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Converting any of those columns to a `varchar` when the column itself is a `nvarchar` and vice versa is going to be terrible for performance. I suspect that the values _aren't_ the values you think; perhaps that have characters that mapped to a `varchar` character that is that character in the other string, or perhaps one column is _meant_ to have a character that can only be in an `nvarchar` but when you handled the data you used an `varchar` at some point, resulting in a `?` character. Can you provide us with a [mre] here?